# It it possible to grab SQL tables from a QuickBooks QBM file. Perhaps there is an SQLite Database in there?

Tags: java, sql, perl, node.js, quickbooks

It would simplify data import for our software if I could export the tables to SQL or CSV or other workable format. We often export from QuickBooks and import into our software and it would be simpler and faster if we could just get the customer's QBM file and then do the rest on our end. We have been exporting individual reports to CSV files, but that is a manual process which we would like to replace with a QBM to SQL tool (or CSV files or Tab Delimited files or other workable format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODBC driver for QuickBooks is avaiable [here](http://qodbc.com/). This driver is based on the QuickBooks SDK. You can find out more about the SDK [here](http://qbsdk.developer.intuit.com/sdk/qb). If you want to build a complex and robust export utility, should consider using the SDK directly. This will involde some development resources, but there's no problem using Java with the SDK if you use the XML API directly rather than the "QBFC" interface which is only support in .NET, VB6, and VBA.

If, on the other hand, you just have some simple exports to get through, I would recommend using an ODBC compatible tool like Excel and forget about writing code. There is [an excellent tool available](http://www.baystateconsulting.com/) that will dispense with ODBC altogether and just do your imports and exports for you. Definitely something to look at.

Finally, if you prefer to use ODBC from Perl or Java that is definitely possible with the QODBC driver. However, it sounds like you'll have to learn how to access ODBC from either Perl or Java since you don't have experience with ODBC. This is not the best way to learn ODBC, since the QODBC driver is a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar requirement in our application and found something called [Quickbooks Data Provider](http://www.rssbus.com/ado/quickbooks/). It’s like a tool that allows you to get information from QB and access it as SQL tables, just like using SQL Server. It’s great because you can manipulate the data in any way you want.

With it you can do something like:

```
QuickBooksConnection cn = new QuickBooksConnection(conString);
QuickBooksCommand cmd = new QuickBooksCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", cn);
QuickBooksDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read()) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(rdr["Id"] + " : " + rdr["Name"]);
}
```

Found it very simple to use, and helped a lot to manipulate the information.

Answer (score 0):

There are ODBC drivers for Quickbooks. I *think* it even ships with one, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Is there a way I could get a hold of one? I can program in Perl, Node.JS, Java. I have never used ODBC, but Java has JDBC which I have used. Any way to get it working in one of those languages?

Comment: Perl has a DBI module. You might be able to use that with perl's DBD::ODBC driver.